# Download Not Working

Tags: java, android

It Just Exits. What's the problem ?

I can't find anything wrong.

If there Is a better Way to download XML to inputstream please let me know.

Or a good way to read 3 or more XMLs simultaneously

```
package com.some.some;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class Login extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        InputStream stream1 = downloadXmlFileStreamUsingUrl("URL IS CORRECT :|");
        // Parse check is login or not ...
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}
public InputStream downloadXmlFileStreamUsingUrl(final String url) {



    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
    String encodedStr = Base64.encodeToString("user:pass".getBytes(), 0);
    getRequest.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedStr);
    HttpClient client = null;
    try {
      client =  new DefaultHttpClient();
      client.getConnectionManager();
      final HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(getRequest);
      final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

      if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        return null;
      }

      final HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
      final InputStream content = getResponseEntity.getContent();
      return content;

    } catch (final IOException e) {
      getRequest.abort();
    }
    finally {
          client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }

        return null;

      }

}
```

Comment: look at the logs and post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you have to understand is where we have to perform network operation.

On google developer docs they had explain step by step process here is [the link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html) and here is one more important [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html) about network operation we perform.

Because the code you have posted I think your running network operation on **main thread**.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` because are trying to access the network from UI.
Starting with Android 3.0 the network access should be done on a separate thread. With other words, `downloadXmlFileStreamUsingUrl()` should run in a separate thread.
You could use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this purpose.